# Should I buy two buckets?

Tags: beer, equipment

There is a sale on homebrew equipment at the moment, and I am adding things to my basket to mimic a starter kit. One thing that I notice is that the kits come with a single fermentation bucket.

Should I get a second for racking or is there a better way?

Comment: More buckets the better!!! :P  They stack. Also if you drill a small hole in the side near the top and plumb in a airlock you can stack several batches.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, get a second bucket. You'll need it for racking. If you plan to use the StarSan sanitizer (recommended) You might even consider a third bucket for holding the StarSan - in an airtight container, StarSan will last a lot longer, so you don't have to make up a fresh batch with each brew or each time you bottle.

Comment: Done. Very excited about my first beer!

Comment: Using distilled water for the star san will also help extend its lifetime significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely want more than one bucket.  You'll need a couple fermenters to keep your pipeline going :) a bottling bucket and as mentioned above possibly a sanitizer bucket.  I also have bucket for soaking labels off bottles.

You don't have buy them though... Check local restaurants and bakeries.  They get foodstuffs delivered in 5 gal food grade buckets all the time and are usually willing to let you have their empties for free.

I get my buckets from a local soap making shop.

Answer (score 0):

Just like everyone has stated, there are always many uses for more buckets. Because they stack so well, I also use them them to store equipment like thermometers, hydros, tubing, etc.